# FireGento_GermanSetup inline translation does not work

Tags: magento-1, localisation, language

If I open the translation for "Incl. 7% Tax, plus Shipping Cost" it says:

```
Location:  Span element 
Scope:  FireGento_GermanSetup 
Shown:  19% 
Original:  %s%% 
Translated:  %s%% 
Store View Specific:  
Custom:  %s%%
```

How can I change the translation text?

Found the source file `price_info.phtml`

```
<span class="tax-details"><?php echo $this->__('Incl. %s Tax, plus <a href="%s">Shipping 
   Cost</a>', $this->getFormattedTaxRate(), $shippingCostUrl) ?></span>
```

This is the [same problem](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/299789/), but the solution does not work for me or I can not make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are situations where the inline translation does not work, because Magento can not identify the correct source string when clicking the translation icon.

You can always do a manual translation.

First you have to identify in from which module the translation comes from. By enabling template-hints you could find out that your translation is printed in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/germansetup/price_info.phtml` via `$this->__()` and `$this` is of the type `FireGento_GermanSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price` the module is `FireGento_GermanSetup`. (there could be rare cases where this is incorrect, if the helper overwrites the module)

If you have a look at `app/locale/de_DE/FireGento_GermanSetup.csv`, you find the translation line:

`"Incl. %s Tax, excl. <a href=""%s"">Shipping Cost</a>","Inkl. %s MwSt., zzgl. <a href=""%s"">Versandkosten</a>"`

Custom translations can be added to a `translate.csv` in your theme (example: `/app/design/frontend/foo/bar/locale/de_DE/translate.csv`) or into the database table `core_translate`.

I suppose you translate the whole application using inline translations, so the `core_translate` table would be the way to go.

No in the `string` column, you have to prefix the string with the module name and `::` resulting in the following fields to fill (`locale`, `store_id` can be copied from your existing entries):

*string:* `FireGento_GermanSetup::Incl. %s Tax, excl. <a href=""%s"">Shipping Cost</a>`
*translate:* `My own text ... Inkl. %s MwSt., zzgl. <a href=""%s"">Versandkosten</a>`

A line in the `translate.csv` would look like this:

`"FireGento_GermanSetup::Incl. %s Tax, excl. <a href=""%s"">Shipping Cost</a>";My own text ... Inkl. %s MwSt., zzgl. <a href=""%s"">Versandkosten</a>"`

Comment: my own translate.csv did not work but app/locale/de_DE/FireGento_GermanSetup.csv does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not change the module translation directly. Did you try to insert the string to `core_translate`. The database has priority over the files.

Comment: Alright, I used `core_translate`. That worked without `FireGento_GermanSetup::` prefix.

Comment: Did it also work with the prefix? Prefixing is more clean but basically has only an effect when in Developer Mode. If it did not work with the prefix I guess there are some module overwrites in place that change the translation module used.